# Автообновление блока

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте, сегодня связался с одной проблемой как автообновление блока AJAX. Проблема собственно в том, что жрет много трафика, хотелось бы сделать, чтобы обновляло при получении новых данных в базу. Вот скрипт динамического обновление который стоит сейчас:

```
function groups()  
        {  
            $.ajax({  
                url: "/obr/groups.php",  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#groups").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
        }  

        $(document).ready(function(){  
            groups();  
            setInterval('groups()',1000);  
        });

<div id="groups"></div>
```

Примечание: скрипт отлично работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Снизить нагрузку таким способом можно только, разве что, сделав обновление намного реже.
Правильный способ - использование сокетов.
В одном сообщение все не уместишь - советую поискать на эту тему информацию, а также очень хорошая статья с тестовым примером чата на php.

[habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/)

Comment: У меня хостинг,  а там под сервер.

Comment: Если хостинг, то уменьшать нагрузку только делая реже обновления. По другому никак. Еще конечно можно проверить все данные на избыточность. Лучше всего передавать все с помощью JSON.

Comment: Я слышал о каком то способе, что можно так сделать, чтобы обновляло при добавлении в БД. Ладно. Поищу если что ещё решений

Comment: Как раз это способ с сокетами. Я про него написал ;)

Comment: Нет, нет, нет я видел другой, вроде через XML

Comment: Ну если найдете, то выложите сюда - всем будет интересно решение.

Comment: Ладно, обязательно выложу.